# How to choose a random element from an array in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

For example, there is a Scala array `val A = Array("please", "help", "me")`. How to choose a random element from this array?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random
// ...
val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
val random_index = rand.nextInt(A.length)
val result = A(random_index)
```

Comment: while the purpose here is insecure pseudo-randomness, it is bad practice to self-seed a RNG unless you really, really know what you are doing. Setting to current time is particularly bad as it significantly narrows the window of possible seeds. For more info see this series: http://jazzy.id.au/default/2010/09/20/cracking_random_number_generators_part_1.html

Comment: scala.util.Random has shuffle, which is much simpler, especially if you need multiple random elements. See answer below.

Comment: this will crash if `A.length` equals to zero. Never forget about edge cases

Comment: This edge case is inherent in the requirement.

Answer (score 95):

```
import scala.util.Random

val A = Array("please", "help", "me")
Random.shuffle(A.toList).head
```

Comment: is it efficient to re-order the whole list and pick the head than just picking in O(1) a value of the array?

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

The question does not specify any efficiency needs, and actually gives an example of a very short Array :)

Comment: Why should it be temporary? It works, and is less prone to any coding error in the array bounds.

Comment: Ought to be `headOption`, since the `Seq` (`Array` here) might be empty.

Comment: A is not empty. It contains three strings.

Answer (score 43):

```
import scala.util.Random

val A = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
A(Random.nextInt(A.size))
```

Comment: this will crash if `A.size` equals to zero. Never forget about edge cases

Comment: Oh, you can use `A.lift(Random.nextInt(A.size))` which will give you `Option[Int]`

Comment: @JonOnstott also will crash if `A.size` is 0

Answer (score 5):

We can also add some safety with the `Option` monad (using the `lift` method)

Actually, when using this method on any collection,
even if your collection is empty, or your random index is out of boundaries, your result will always be an Option.

#### Drive safe <3

```
def getRandElemO[T](arr: Array[T]): Option[T] =
  if (arr.isEmpty) None
  else arr.lift(util.Random.nextInt(arr.length))

// or the one liner:
// def getRandElemO[T](arr: Array[T]): Option[T] =
//   arr.headOption.flatMap(_ => arr.lift(util.Random.nextInt(arr.length)))
```

Comment: Note that it is not technically referencially transparent since two calls with the same parameter won't give the same result. To achieve this you would have to pass the RNG instance in params as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more idiomatic solution, consider using the typeclass pattern (implicit classes in scala).

```
implicit class ListOps[A](list: List[A]) {
  def getRandomElement: Option[A] = list match {
    case Nil => None
    case _ => list.lift(scala.util.Random.nextInt(list.size))
  }
  def randomChoice(n: Int): Option[List[A]] =
    (1 to n).toList.foldLeft(Option(List[A]()))((acc, e) => getRandomElement.flatMap(r => acc.map(a => a :+ r)))
}
```

Now if the implicit class is in scope, you can:

```
val randomElement: Option[String] = List("this", "is", "a", "list").getRandomElement
```

If you are sure that the option contains some value, you can use the `get` method.

```
randomElement.get // This will return a String (or a NotSuchElementExeption)
```

Nonetheless, pattern matching or `getOrElse` are recommended:

```
randomElement match {
  case None => ??? // This is what you do when a None is encounter (e.g. for empty lists)
  case Some(result) => ??? // The variable result contains a string.
```

**Note** that the `randomChoice` method assumes substitution of elements.

Answer (score 1):

A better answer that does not involve reshuffling the array at all would be this:

```
import scala.util.Random

object sample {
  //gets random element from array
  def arr[T](items:Array[T]):T = {
    items(Random.nextInt(items.length))
  }
}
```

This also works generically

Comment: Consider sample.arr[Int](Array[Int]())