# Efficient way to get a random element in Scala?

Tags: scala, random

What is an efficient way to get a random element from a collection in Scala? There's a related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051574/how-to-choose-a-random-element-from-an-array-in-scala), but like one of the comments pointed out, "[that] question does not specify any efficiency needs".

Comment: In case `size` method is efficient you should use `apple(randomIndexLessThanSize)`. In general there is no such method: for instance you can't get fair random element from infinite collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An arbitrary collection cannot be accessed in constant time. So you need some special collection with the desired property. For instance — `Vector` or `Array`. See [Performance Characteristics of collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html) for others.

Answer (score 2):

```
util.Random.shuffle(List.range(1,100)) take 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a collection with a constant-time size() and get() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you need random order of all collection elements, then `Random.shuffle` is what you need. (You'd better convert the original collection to array to avoid forward and backward conversion.)