# How get random element from list in one line

Tags: scala

I have following code:

```
val A = List(...)
val items = A.map(..magic#1..).filter(..magic#2..).map(..magic#3..)
val rndItem = items(Random.nextInt(items.size))
```

But I want this:

```
val A = List(...)
val rndItem = A.map(..magic#1..).filter(..magic#2..).map(..magic#3..).getRandom()
```

Can I do this on scala?

I seen [question#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675032/efficient-way-to-get-a-random-element-in-scala) and [question#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051574/how-to-choose-a-random-element-from-an-array-in-scala)

Comment: I don't think so, unless you will write some helper code (most likely using pimp-my-library pattern), but is this an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - use the pimp my library pattern to "add a method" to `List`:

```
// We'll use a value class to avoid allocations (in theory anyway)
implicit class RandomList[A](val self: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def getRandom(): A = self(Random.nextInt(self.size))
}
```

See also:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html
- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html