# How to return multiple random elements from List scala

Tags: scala

How can I return multiple random elements from a List .

This question [How to choose a random element from an array in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051574/how-to-choose-a-random-element-from-an-array-in-scala) refers to using :

```
import scala.util.Random
val A = Array("please", "help", "me")
Random.shuffle(A.toList).head
```

The mutable in me is thinking I could create a for loop and keep selecting the next random element (excluding the one already selected) and add that to a new List. Is there a more idiomatic/functional way to achieve this in Scala ?

Comment: `Random.shuffle(A.toList).take(n)`

Comment: "take" implements this using a loop. It is probably explained by the performance reasons.

Comment: @HappyCoder: yes, `Random.shuffle(A.toIndexedSeq).take(n)` is better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `head` method will return the first element of the list, but `take(n)` will return up to  `n` elements from the front of the list. So after you shuffle the list, just use `take`:

```
def takeRandomN[A](n: Int, as: List[A]) =
  scala.util.Random.shuffle(as).take(n)
```

If your list `as` is shorter than `n` then this will simply shuffle `as`.

It might seem like this is going to be slow for large lists that you only want a small subset from, but a random subset will be likely be uniformly sampled from the list, so you'll have to traverse the whole thing anyway. For an `Array` or other structure with random access, you can do better, but for `List` you cannot.

Comment: Just a note that this is fine for small lists but with big ones that you want a small random subset for this can be painfully slow.

Comment: @Shawn from curiosity what would be efficient for big list/sets?

Comment: Shuffle is O(n). I'm not sure you can do better.

Answer (score 1):

More "conservative" variant without using mutables/vars. Just for the sake of exercise:

```
def takeRandomFrom[T](n: Int, list: List[T]): List[T] = {
  @tailrec
  def innerTake(n:Int, list: List[T], result: List[T]): List[T] = {
    if (n == 0 || list.isEmpty) {
  result
} else {
  innerTake(n - 1, list.tail, list.head :: result)
}
  }

  innerTake(n, Random.shuffle(list), Nil)
}  

takeRandomFrom(2, Array("please", "help", "me").toList)
```